# how to make cart not resize on desktop view

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm making a front-end challenge which asks you to create a simple card and display it in mobile view and desktop view with the same aspect.

I used a mobile-first approach to this as in each of my projects problem here is that card is resizing in desktop view changing the look of itself

here is the reference I used:
[image]

here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: hsl(212, 45%, 89%);
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-inline: 1rem;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: .75rem;
}

h1 {
  color: hsl(218, 44%, 22%);
}

p {
  color: hsl(220, 15%, 55%);
}

#qr_card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: hsl(0 0% 100%);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}

#card_description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="qr_card">
    <img src="images/image-qr-code.png" alt="qr" />
    <section id="card_description">
      <h1>Improove your front-end skills by building projects</h1>
      <p>Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level</p>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

everything looks normal in mobile view but I can't figure out how to make the card not change in size in desktop view without setting a fixed width property on the card itself

Comment: set a max-width to your card

Comment: I don't have the actual width

Answer (score 0):

You can set for example `aspect-ratio: 1/2` to lock the height to the width.